# Get summary data per tf.name_scope from TensorBoard

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I've used `with tf.name_scope(...)` in my program to separate out a few different parts of the graph.

This works nicely in the TensorBoard graph view, I can view these functions as subgraphs. However, what I'd like to do is profile how much time (in total) was spent in each of these functions.

I've looked at the TraceViewer tool (https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/profiler#trace_viewer). I can zoom right in and see individual operations, each one have a long name which includes the name_scopes I have defined. I can see the "Wall duration" for each in the details pane.

But I can't see a way to get a summary of **total CPU time spent per name_scope** or any kind of summary of aggregate times (this is the sort of thing I'd expect to get from a more typical profiling tool in Python, time spent per function). Is there any way to get such a summary?

(I should say that my program is a TF-compiled state space model, not a Keras model. I've exported my trace "manually" with `tf.summary.trace_export`. So I can't see some of the profiling outputs that are shown on the TensorBoard docs pages. I can only see the Profile (Trace Viewer) and Graph pages in TensorBoard.)

Many thanks in advance for any advice.